# Unable to install Joomla on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I installed xampp server on my system with port number 90 because I have another server running on my system. Also, MySQL uses port 3308. The xampp server is running well, Apache runs correctly, MySQL runs correctly and the PHPMyAdmin also runs correctly.

But when I was trying to install Joomla 3.6, I received an error message "The installer was not able to connect to the MySQL server. Please make sure MySQL is running".

Note: I did not create password for MySQL.

What else am I suppose to do to get Joomla installed and running correctly?

Comment: Have you already created the database or are you creating a new one in the UI?

Comment: So, as you mentioned, you are running _MySQL_ on 3308 port instead of 3306. Now the question is are you using same 3308 port for your Joomla configuration or your Joomla is looking for MySQL on port 3306?

Comment: @Ehsan I suspect Joomla is looking for MySQL on port 3306. Interms of Joomla configuration, I haven't done any because I am just trying to install it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configurate the correct port for your MySQLi database connection. Maybe your joomla setup use the 3306 port for the mysql. change this to 3308 in the configuration file inside the installation folder before you start to setup the CMS.

```
/* Database Settings */
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';               // Normally mysqli
public $host = 'localhost:3308';              // This is normally set to localhost
public $user = '';                       // DB username
public $password = '';                   // DB password
public $db = '';                         // DB database name
public $dbprefix = 'jos_';               // Do not change unless you need to!
```

Comment: Yes joomla is trying to connect through 3306

Answer (score 1):

I changed MySQL port configuration from port 3308 back to port 3306.
Then I try to install Joomla again and it successfully installed.
To make it connect on port 3308:
-Change the MySQL port configuration from 3306 back to 3308.
-Locate Joomla C:\xampp\apps
C:\xampp\apps\joomla\htdocs
-Then open the configuration file with notepad
-Change the port settings from 3306 to 3308 "public $host = 'localhost:3308';"
That is how I solved the problem.